# How to run Airflow Web Console on different port?

Tags: airflow

Today, I was trying to run the web console of **airflow port other than 8080 like 80, 8090** but every time I was mentioning a different port in **airflow.cfg** and re-initialize the airflow and run *airflow webserver -D*

But every time the web console was running at port 8080 can anyone help or encountered this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the port on airflow.cfg after you save the file, you shall run `airflow db init` and start airflow webserver again `airflow webserver -D`

[image: changes on airflow.cfg - web_server_port and base_url]

If you are using docker image that will be different. You need change you `docker-compose.yaml` file

Comment: Hey, actually I found the issue. the main issue was that I have installed the airflow with some user and that user doesn't have sudo access and I was trying to launch the airflow on port 80 or 443. Post which I tried on port 8090 and that worked for me is there any way I can launch the airflow webserver on port 80?

Comment: @Mukul ports 0-1023 are reserved and require special privileges to bind.

Comment: Yes. That I know should I do the port forwarding

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to use cap_net_bind_service=+ep with airflow?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running airflow in the docker then you have make changes in the docker-compose.yaml file. In that file we will have airflow-webserver, under this we have option of ports. there we have to give our new port number.

ports:
- "8081:8080"

8081 is  the new port number and 8080 is the old one